# why javascript can't catch json attribute value

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

In SpringBoot, I get a JSON data, including some attribute , but I can't catch its attribute in JavaScript , like

```
  var article = $ {
      json(article)
    };
    var htmlContent = article.author;
```

In the Chrome Development tool, I can see 
[image]

but Console can print

```
article.author
"aaa"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. *"but Console can print ... How can I fix it?"* What's wrong with the output? What exactly do you want to fix?

Comment: How can I use  'document.getElementById('HTML_content').innerHTML = htmlContent; ' when my element in script Tag, there will appear 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

Comment: Why is this not part of your question? How should we have known which problem you have? Either way, the error means that JavaScript cannot find an element with ID `HTML_content `. You have to make sure that the element exists: that you have no typo in the ID and that you run the code after the element was created.

Comment: I can find it when it exclude the script tag , I don't know why 
   .$(document).ready(
        function () {
            document.getElementById('HTML_content').innerHTML = htmlContent;
            ...